# clojure/clojurescript change just one key in nested map

Tags: replace, clojure, nested-map

I have this map:

```
{:a {:a {:a 1 :b 2}}}
```

And I want to turn it into this one:

```
{:a {:a {:x 1 :b 2}}}
```

I tried this, but -of course- got *all* `:a` replaced:

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk-replace {:a :c} {:a {:a {:a 1 :b 2}}})

-> {:c {:c {:c 1, :b 2}}}
```

I tried this, but got a result I can't even interpret:

```
(update-in {:a {:a {:a 1 :b 2}}} [:a :a] clojure.walk/postwalk-replace {:a :c})

-> {:a {:a {1 :c}}}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `clojure.set/rename-keys`.  E.g.

```clj
(update-in {:a {:a {:a 1 :b 2}}} [:a :a] clojure.set/rename-keys {:a :c})
; → {:a {:a {:b 2, :c 1}}}
```

The reason, why your example fails is the argument order.
`postwalk-replace` needs the first argument to be the replacement map
and the second argument to what is to be renamed.  But `update-in`
always sends the traversed things as first argument into the function.
So you need to juggle the arguments around (e.g. via an anon-fn or with
`partial`):

```clj
(update-in {:a {:a {:a 1 :b 2}}} [:a :a] (partial clojure.walk/postwalk-replace {:a :c}))
; → {:a {:a {:b 2, :c 1}}}
```